# compute the value of a special function in $x=1$

Tags: calculus

Let a function $f:[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous(even analytic) function on $[0,1]$. If $f(1)=2\int_0^\frac12xf(x)dx$, then  $f(1)=$?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition does not define a function.

In fact, I can choose **any** integrable function $f$ on [0,1/2], then define the restriction of $f$ on [1/2,1] to be the affine function such that $f(1):=2\int_0^\frac12xf(x)dx.$